# Communication between objects (in C++)

Tags: c++, object, communication, interaction

I am **currently coding my biggest C++ program, using multiple objects** to manage a windows (using Windows API functions), a 3D engine (DirectX), and other objects all having to work together to accomplish their task.

**I have some problems to organize my objects so they can interact with each other intelligently.**
When an object has to perform operations, or worse, pass parameters to another object, **I struggle to define the best solution to harmonise and organize my code.**

***Here is an excellent example:***

As I said, in my program I have 2 objects: (1) *"windowManager"* which handles all the operations related to the window itself, and (2) *"rendererManager"* which handles all my DirectX operations, from the initialisation to the rendering of every frame.

When the window get resized, DirectX has to be reset to adjust the drawing area, otherwise the image gets stretched, so "windowManager" has to be able to order "rendererManager" to reset.

I could not think of a better solution than to create a *"rendererManager.Reset()"* method, then 2 methods for the window manager *"windowManager.GetRequestRendererReset()"* and *"windowManager.SetRequestRendererReset(bool reset)"*

When my window get resized, the object *"windowManager"* calls its own method *"windowManager.SetRequestRendererReset(true)"* to change one of his arguments that can be queried from a "get method".
With this, in my main cycle (in the infinite loop in the main) I applied some verification such as:

```
if (windowManager.GetRequestRendererReset()) { // The window has been resized, we need to reset DirectX
    rendererManager.Reset(windowManager.GetWindow());
    windowManager.SetRequestRendererReset(false);
}
```

This feels very sub-optimal and I feel that there is a better solution.
In addition to this, I now need to send more complex information to my object *"rendererManager"*, such as text to write in the image at specific location, and without an intelligent organization my whole code might become swampy.

**Is there some guidelines on how to optimise interactions and communications between objects?**
Do you have a good lesson/tutorial about this, or do you have examples of good practices?

Comment: For the specific scenario you describe, using an event mechanism is a very solid approach. The window manager can expose a function that takes another function and calls it whenever it is resized. The consuming rendererManager, can easily interact with this by passing a lambda/function pointer/std::function/etc

Comment: Thank you Aluan, I have never written an event mechanism. Would you have a lesson or tutorial to learn this? I am going to research this tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any good tutorials for event handling in C++ offhand. Here is how I would do it though: In window manager there would be a field: `std::vector<std::function<void (Rect)>> resize_handlers;` and a function `void on_resize(std::function<void(Rect)> eventHandler) { resizeHandlers.push_back(handler); }` and when the window is resized it will invoke them all like `for (auto f: resize_handlers) { f(Bounds); }`

Comment: Then with `rendererManager`, you would register a handler like `windowManager.on_resize([&](auto rect) { rendererManager.something(); });`

Comment: Wow, thank you very much Aluan, I definitely need to read more about event handling to be able to understand your solution and to deploy it in my project, but I think I will understand the concept. After a good night of sleep :)

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. Note that while the pattern involves events (conceptually) the core concepts (and all of the code) revolves around a much more fundamental concept: Higher order functions. We have a function that takes a function as a parameter, a collection of functions, and an inline function value with lexical scope. You may want to read about functions as values in C++